# How much of a deterrent is deep and wide water to the Terminators depicted in the Terminator Universe?

Tags: the-terminator, the-terminator-series

Is there any canon information regarding how much of a deterrent deep and wide water would be to the infiltration units depicted in the Terminator Universe?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In the episode ["The Mousetrap"](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/Episode_203:_The_Mousetrap) of *The Sarah Connor Chronicles*, the Series 888 Terminator named "Cromartie" couldn't swim, sank to the bottom of the ocean, and had to walk along the bottom until it got to the shore.

Comment: I never remember SCC. I probably watched 5 or 6 episodes.

Comment: @MajorStackings : Same here.  This happened to be one of the 5 or 6 that I caught.  :-)